# Data Grid and View State C#

Tags: gridview, viewstate

If the view state of a data grid is disabled and the page having the data grid view is reloaded 
by pressing F5. what will happen to the values of the data grid?

Comment: You should include the code in the question. But the most likely answer is that the grid view data will be reloaded from it source

Comment: Assuming this is web, even with Viewstate enabled, if the page was loaded using a `GET` request, F5 will repeat that `GET` and the Viewstate will not be sent. Therefore the grid will likely be reloaded from source.

Comment: thanks to both of you for gave suggestion on it.